# Create custom button which does not redirect to a page

Tags: custom-button

I want to create a custom button on a custom object which when pressed executes a script on an external site without redirecting to that page.

Currently when the button is pressed the only behavior options are :

1. Display in new window
2. Display in existing window with sidebar
3. Display in existing window without sidebar
4. Display in existing window without sidebar or header
5. Execute JavaScript

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried `Execute Javascript` as Behavior?

Comment: I can't see why some magic with the Execute JavaScript option won't assist you in your requirement?

Comment: Could you please explain how to use JavaScript to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute javascript (option 5); call the other page via ajax; and execute your procedure based on the result of your ajax request.